# how to merge different key value pairs in python based on value of a key?

Tags: python

I am trying to get some data from remote server based on fields provided in HTTP/POST request. There are some 1500 fields, however at any given time I can query only 30 fields. So I am breaking the 1500 fields in 50 chucks and making 50 requests to remote host. Return data contains 5000 json records for each 30 fields. I want to merge results from all 50 requests and load final data in MongoDB. I developed following code, is there a better or efficient solution?

```
import requests
import json
import time 
current_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

#certain code ommited 
main_data_list=[]
i=0
n=30
# there are about 1500 data fields, separated by 30 chuncks
for r in data_field_chuncks:
    rr = '"name" , '+', '.join('"{0}"'.format(w) for w in r)
    ##print (rr)       
    query_data = rr
    keys = json.loads(query_data)
    response = requests.post('remote_host', headers=headers, data=query_data)
    response_data = json.loads(response.text)
    
    
    for r in response_data['data']:
        # there are about 5000 different names
       
        fieldvalues = (r['d'][0:len(keys['columns'])])
        json_lines = {}
        for n, v in zip(keys['columns'], fieldvalues):
            json_lines[n.replace(".","_").replace("|","__").replace("[","_").replace("]","_")] = v   
        if i==0:
            json_lines["t"] = current_time
            #print (json_lines)
            main_data_list.append(json_lines)            
        else:
            for sub_list in main_data_list:
                #each time there will be 5000 look ups
                if sub_list['name']==json_lines['name']:
                    sub_list.update(json_lines)
            
    i=i+1
    time.sleep(1)

for line in main_data_list:
    mongo_database.insert_one(line)
```

Comment: Please add a example of data_field_chuncks

Comment: data_field_chunks = {'key1','key2','key3',...,'key30'}, is mainly used as a quote separated list the is being used in HTTP/POST, return data contains only data , from which I created key value pairs for entry into main_data_list

Comment: keys = json.loads(query_data) dont works

Comment: please use this: query_data = '{  "fields": [    "key1",    "key2",    "key3"  ]}'

Comment: how sure are you the records are in order for all 50 queries

Comment: @rioV8 , very sure, the records will be ordered